# Chrome/firefox extension javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make an extension for google meet, and wanted to do tabs as a menu for selecting different functions. When I load index.html in browser everything seems to work fine, but once imported as an extension the tabs stop working.
I was following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Manifest:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Google Meet Manager",
    "description": "Google Meet Manager: on time, number of members, minutes",
    "version": "1.2.1",
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "addon@Gorbiel",
            "strict_min_version": "42.0"
        }
    },
    "author": "Gorbiel",
    "icons": {
        "512": "images/logo-512px.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/logo-32px.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Google Meet Manager"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://meet.google.com/*",
        "https://meet.google.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "background.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "http://meet.google.com/*",
                "https://meet.google.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Google Meet Manager v1.2.1</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="sidebar">
                <button class="tablinks" onClick="openTab(event, 'main')">
                    <div class="sidebarLogoIcon"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="tablinks" onClick="openTab(event, 'exit')">
                    <div class="sidebarExitIcon"></div>
                </button>
                <button class="tablinks" onClick="openTab(event, 'options')">
                    <div class="sidebarSettingsIcon"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div id="exit" class="tabcontent">
                <div class="heading">Auto Exit based on:</div>
                <div class="timeicon"></div>
                <div class="membericon"></div>
                <div class="minutesicon"></div>
                <div class="enter">ENTER:</div>
                <input type="time" class="inputvalue">
                <div class="hourglassicon"></div>
                <div class="confirmIcon"></div>
                <div class="CancelIcon"></div>
                <script src="vmaster.js"></script>
            </div>
            
            <div id="options" class="tabcontent">
                <div class="heading">Settings</div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="main" class="tabcontent">
                <div class="heading">Logo page</div>
            </div>
            
            <script src="tabs.js"></script>
            
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

body{
    margin: 0px 0px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #444444;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.sidebar button.active {
  background-color: #444444;
}
.sidebarLogoIcon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/logoBW-40px.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.sidebarExitIcon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/exit-40px.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.sidebarSettingsIcon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 155px;
    left: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/settings-40px.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.heading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 65px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
.timeicon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 75px;
    background-image: url(images/clock-40px.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height:40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.timeicon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.membericon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 130px;
    background-image: url(images/members-40px.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height:40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.membericon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.minutesicon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 190px;
    background-image: url(images/stopwatch-40px.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height:40px;
    width: 40px;
}
.minutesicon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.enter{
    position:absolute;
    top: 102px;
    left:172px;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    color: #b3b3b3
}
.confirmIcon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 155px;
    left: 157px;
    background-image: url(images/confirm-32px.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height:32px;
    width: 32px;

}
.confirmIcon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.CancelIcon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 155px;
    left: 196px;
    background-image: url(images/cancel-32px.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height:32px;
    width: 32px;

}
.CancelIcon:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inputvalue{
    position: absolute;
    top:125px;
    left: 125px;
}
.inputvalue:hover{
    cursor: text;
}
.hourglassicon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 65px;
    background-image: url(images/animated.gif);
    background-size: contain;
    height:48px;
    width: 48px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

tabs.js:

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  console.log(tabcontent);
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  console.log(tabcontent);
  
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  console.log(tablinks);
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  console.log(tablinks);
  
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Here's the link to the branch on github if you need additional files: https://github.com/Gorbiel/Google-Meet-Manager/tree/main-newUI

Comment: Do you get any errors? Anything in developer tools console?

Comment: that's the weird part - I didn't see anything. It's almost as if it ignores the whole tabs.js file

Comment: I suspect that this is happening because the document.getElementsByClassName is searching through the active webpage rather than the index.html file, but I have no idea how to change that